# Adding rows to SQL query result

Tags: postgresql

I have a custom query in my Java application that looks like that:

```
select 
    to_char(search.timestamp,'Mon') as mon, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(search.ip_address))
from 
    searches 
WHERE 
    searches.city = 1 
group by 1;
```

which should return all months that occur within the database, and number of distinct IP addresses within each month. However, at this point, some months do not have any entries, and they are missing in the SQL query result. How can I make sure that all of the months are displayed there, even if their count is 0?

Got it working with:

```
select  
    to_char (gs.m,'Mon') as mon,  
    count (distinct search.ip_address) 
from
    generate_series (
          date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '11 month'),
          current_date,
          '1 month'
      ) gs (m)
    left join searches
    on date_trunc('month', search.timestamp) = gs.m AND search.city = 1
group by gs.m 
order by gs.m;
```

Comment: You need a table with the months in it as your base table and then join `searches` to that.

Comment: @bernie, that seems like a great idea. Would I just store names of the month over there, of timestamps which correspond to the months of the given years (for example all months for 2016,2017 etc.)

Comment: Sure, preferably you'd store the names of the months and the years.

Comment: `distinct` is not a function. There is no need for the parentheses. `distinct a` is the same as `distinct (a)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for a tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    to_char (gs.m,'Mon') as mon, 
    count (distinct(search.ip_address))
from 
    searches
    right join
    generate_series (
        date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '1 year'),
        current_date,
        '1 month'
    ) gs (m) on date_trunc('month', search.timestamp) = gs.m
where searches.city = 1 
group by gs.m
order by gs.m;
```

Comment: Is it possible for this method to generate last 12 months in order from the oldest month?

Comment: @Coldoaldo, this only returns table with one month -> "Mar -> count". I was hoping to see something like this: "April -> count", "May -> count", "June -> count" etc. :( - business logic behind this: I need to see the month even though there has been no records in it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (untested):

```
select 
    months.mon
    , COUNT(DISTINCT(searchs.ip_address))
from 
    (select 
        to_char(searches.timestamp,'Mon') as mon
     from 
        searches
     group by 1
    ) months
    left join searches 
    on to_char(searchs.timestamp,'Mon') = months.mon
    and searches.city = 1 
group by 1;
```

And if you wanted the years in there, too, try something like this (untested):

```
select 
    months.mon
    , COUNT(DISTINCT(searchs.ip_address))
from 
    (select 
        extract(year from searches.timestamp) as yr
        , to_char(searches.timestamp,'Mon') as mon
        , to_char(yr,'9999') || mon yrmon
     from 
        searches
     group by 1
    ) months
    left join searches 
    on to_char(extract(year from searches.timestamp),'9999' || 
        to_char(searchs.timestamp,'Mon') = months.yrmon
    and searches.city = 1 
group by 1;
```